# Datagridview some columns accept only string , numeric and and some specific format

Tags: c#, validation, datatable, datagridview, insertion

I am working on Datagridview and I have multiple columns. Some columns must accept the only numeric value, some only accept a string only, and some columns accept a specific format like 0000-0000-0000. I used the below code:

```
 private void adgUser_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (adgUser.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 0)
        {
            e.Control.KeyPress -= AllowLettersOnly;
            e.Control.KeyPress += AllowLettersOnly;
        }
        if (adgUser.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 1)
        {
            e.Control.KeyPress -= AllowLettersOnly;
            e.Control.KeyPress += AllowLettersOnly;
        }

        if (adgUser.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 2)
        {
            e.Control.KeyPress -= AllowNumbersOnly;
            e.Control.KeyPress += AllowNumbersOnly;
        }           
    }       

    private void AllowNumbersOnly(Object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
            e.Handled = true;
    }
    private void AllowLettersOnly(Object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsWhiteSpace(e.KeyChar))
            e.Handled = true;
    }
```

Now, this code is not working fine. I am inserting data through datagridview into the database table and make sure columns only accept valid format while inserting data. Please advise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspected you're not assigning `KeyPress` handlers to the `TexBox` control hidden inside the `DataGrdivView` and looked around and found this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31172081/vb-net-2010-datagridview-handling-keypress-via-editingcontrolshowing-event), applied it to your example and it works as expected:

```
private void adgUser_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox txtEdit = e.Control;
    txtEdit.MaxLength = 2;

    // remove any existing handler
    txtEdit.KeyPress -= txtdgvDiaryEdit_Keypress;
    txtEdit.KeyPress += txtdgvDiaryEdit_Keypress;
}

private void txtdgvDiaryEdit_Keypress(object sender, Global.System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    // Test for numeric value or backspace 
    if (Information.IsNumeric(e.KeyChar.ToString()) | e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Back)
    {
        e.Handled = false; // if numeric  
    }
    else
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }  // if non numeric 
}
```

This only allows two digits. Obviously, you have to apply your constraints (numbers, letters, length,...), but the logic is what you're after, I believe.